# Was that Karl actually singing?

Tags: an-idiot-abroad

At the very end of season 2 of An Idiot Abroad, Karl is shown in the closing credits singing with Chas and Dave.  I am, however, dubious as to whether that was ACUALLY Karl singing, or if it was edited to make it appear as though Karl was singing.

So, at the end of season 2, was that actually Karl singing?

Comment: What makes you think it's not him?

Comment: @Walt might have been the production but it didn't quite sound like him, although some people's singing voices are different from how they talk.

Comment: I've not watched Season 2 - hence I'm not putting this as an answer.  Perhaps "Ain't no pleasing you"?  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9QvWK4vpjY0

Comment: @iandotkelly that is most likely it, can't watch it at the moment

Comment: @iandotkelly [Makes sense](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2097372/soundtrack).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, that's really him singing 'Ain't No Pleasing You'.**

- [He's filmed singing it in a recording studio](http://youtube.com/watch?v=9QvWK4vpjY0);
- It sounds exactly like Karl (to me, anyway);
- *Many* publications confirm it's him singing (like [this one](https://www.digitalspy.com/music/a354716/karl-pilkington-song-unlikely-to-be-released-for-christmas/));
- [He's listed on IMDb as the song's performer](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2097372/soundtrack):

> Ain't No Pleasing You
>   Written by Chas & Dave
>   **Performed by Chas & Dave with Karl Pilkington**
>   Played over the end credits